# Find the maximum and minimum value of $w^2$+$x^2$+ $y^2$+ $z^2$ given the following conditions?

Tags: number-theory

[image: Maximum and Minimum]

**MyApproach**

I tried adding consecutive natural numbers.I also tried adding consecutive  odd numbers.I also tried adding consecutive  even numbers.

But I am not getting their sum of the form 8m+10.

> Can anyone guide me how to approach the problem?

Comment: I assume the title ought to refer to $w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$?   Also, not sure I understand your approach.  there are no obstructions to having $4$ natural numbers add to some large target...here you could have $w=8m+7$, $x,y,z=1$ for an example at one extreme (most unequal).  Or you could take the quadruple $\{2m+2,2m+2,2m+3,2m+3\}$ for an example at the other extreme (most equal).

Comment: @lulu How you get to this approach?Because In exams I need to think like that.

Comment: Short answer:  looking at $(a-n)^2+(a+n)^2=2a^2+2n^2$ we see that, if $a+b$ is fixed, $a^2+b^2$ is maximized when $a,b$ are as far apart as possible, and minimized when they are as close as possible.  Longer answer:  Lagrange multipliers tells us that one extreme is obtained when all are equal, the other must lie on the edge.

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy Schwarz inequality, you have
$$w^2+x^2+y^2+z^2\ge \frac{(w+x+y+z)^2}4=16m^2+40m+25$$

However to attain this minimum, all numbers have to be equal, which is not possible for natural numbers adding to $8m+10$. The next best choice is the next natural number, $16m^2+40m+26$ which is attainable using two each from $2m+2, 2m+3$, so that is the answer.

The maximum OTOH is $(8m+7)^2+1^2+1^2+1^2=64m^2+112m+52$ which is much larger than the choices given.

Comment: Can you explain what it mean and how it is relevant in the problem.Because linking them will make me easy to understand and I can apply the approach anywhere.

Comment: Which element do you have trouble with? The approach is to find the min and maximum possible among all positive reals, then testing how close one gets with naturals satisfying the sum constraint.

Comment: $(w+x+y+z^$2$)/$4$ How u get this?

Comment: For that you should read up and try Cauchy Schwarz inequality - easily available on the web. A simple proof is to observe $2a^2+2b^2\ge (a+b)^2$ as this is equivalent to $(a-b)^2\ge0$. Now substitute $a\to w+x $ and $b\to y+z$, use the earlier inequality on each of the terms in LHS.

Answer (score 0):

If $w\geq x\geq2$ then
$$(w+1)^2+(x-1)^2=w^2+x^2+2(w-x)+2>w^2+x^2\ .$$
It follows that we can enlarge the sum $q$ of the four squares without changing  $w+x+y+z$, as long as two of the variables are $\geq2$. The maximum possible $q$ is therefore given by
$$q_\max=(8m+7)^2+1+1+1=64m^2+112m+52\ .$$
On the other hand, if $w-x\geq2$ then
$$(w-1)^2+(x+1)^2=w^2+x^2-2(w-x)+2\leq w^2+x^2-2<w^2+x^2\ .$$
It follows that we can decrease the sum $q$ of the four squares without changing  $w+x+y+z$, as long as two of the variables differ by $\geq2$. The minimum possible $q$ is therefore given by a configuration where all differences between the variables are $\leq1$. It follows that
$$q_\min=2(2m+2)^2+2(2m+3)^2=16m^2+40m +26\ ,$$
whereby it has played a rôle that $10\equiv2$ modulo $4$.